# SQLite order by column difference

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Is it allowed to do something like this:

`select * from table order by (c1-c2) desc`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What you wrote will work exactly as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT *, (c1-c2) as diff FROM tabel ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Your query works just fine too, just tested here.

Comment: Is that better (performance wise) than the select query I posted?

Comment: I believe it is worse than yours, since it passes the difference of the columns in the results. If you don't care about them your way is probably better.